# How to deal with functions that approach infinity in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, math

In a book on matplotlib I found a plot of 1/sin(x) that looks similar to this one that I made:

[image]

I used the domain

```
input = np.mgrid[0 : 1000 : 200j]
```

What confuses me here to an extreme extent is the fact that the sine function is just periodic. I don't understand why the maximal absolute value is decreasing. Plotting the same function in wolfram-alpha does not show this decreasing effect. Using a different step-amount

```
input = np.mgrid[0 : 1000 : 300j]
```

delivers a different result:

[image]

where we also have this decreasing tendency in maximal absolute value.

So my questions are:

1. How can I make a plot like this consistent i.e. independent of step-size/step-amount?
2. Why does one see this decreasing tendency even though the function is purely periodic?

Comment: Could you post the code you use to generate the plots, please? How do you handle the divide by zero errors?

Comment: Related: this [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)

Comment: The short answer for 1. is: You can't. The step size needs to be above a certain threshold.

Comment: @L.Grozinger The code to plot is very basic and I feel it would clutter an already long post. I have not had any errors because of division by 0 that I would have had to handle. At e.g. 0 the result array just reads `inf` so I imagine NumPy handles that error internally.

Answer (score 2):

The period of the sine function is rather higher than what is plotted, so what you’re seeing is **aliasing** from the difference in the sampling frequency and some multiple of the true frequency.  Since one of the roots is at 0, the smallest discrepancy that happens to exist between the first few samples and a
multiple of π itself **scales** linearly away from 0, producing a 1/*x* envelope.

In this example, `input[5]` is 5(1000/(200-1))=8π−0.007113, so the function is about −141 there, as shown.  `input[10]` is of course 16π−0.014226, so that the function is about −70, and so on as long as the discrepancy is much smaller than π.

It’s possible for some one of the quasi-periodic sample sequences to eventually land even closer to *n*π, producing a more complicated pattern like that in the second plot.

Comment: Thank you for the aliasing reference, that made things a lot more clear. Could you expand your explanation on the 1/x envelope a bit? That one I don't quite get yet.

Answer (score 1):

### Why does one see this decreasing tendency even though the function is purely periodic?

Keep in mind that actually at every multiple of `pi` the function goes to infinity. And the size of the jump displayed actually only reflects the biggest value of the sampled values where the function still made sense. Therefore you get a big jump if you happen to sample a value were the function is big but not too big to be a float.

To be able to plot anything `matplotlib` throws away values that do not make sense. Like the `np.nan` you get at multiples of `pi` and `±np.infs` you get for values very close to that. I believe what happens is that one step size away from zero you happen to get a value small enough not to be thrown away but still very large. While when you get to `pi` and multiples of it the largest value gets thrown away.

### How can I make a plot like this consistent i.e. independent of step-size/step-amount?

You get strange behaviour around the values where your function becomes unreasonable large. Just pick a `ylimit` to avoid plotting those crazy large values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

x = np.linspace(10**-10,50, 10**4)
plt.plot(x,1/np.sin(x))
plt.ylim((-15,15))
```

[image]